# Problem upgrading 2013 SP1 to 2013 SP1 HR1

Tags: 2013, 2013-sp1-hr1

Migrating from 2013 SP1 to 2013 SP1 HR1 in our windows server 2012 R2, we've got the following error when running the installer to apply the hotfix rollup to your Content Manager server. The error shown is:

> Some or all identity references could not be translated

Any ideas? We've already updated the content manager db without problems.

Comment: There has to be some log somewhere. Check the Event Viewer, then look in the installer temp directory or installation folder (it's gotta be somewhere).  In the log look for a stacktrace and paste it by updating the question for us to peel our eyes at.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error was that we changed the machine name after the initial tridion installation.

Tridion installation wrote in the regedit the name of the machine. Then, the installation of the patch was failing.

We changed the regedit tridion value and then installed the patch successfully.
We achieved to see that, executing a repair of the CM, which was failing, and seeing the log.

Comment: Which regedit entry is it?

Answer (score 1):

Googling the error message suggests that this is a problem related to your system's/account's folder permissions.

This forum thread (https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/70a4ed80-bafb-4fb6-bbf6-c8eec071ae4c/some-or-all-identity-references-could-not-be-translated) gives some clues:

> It maybe like some of the folder/directory the user you are logged in
>   with doesn't have rights to grant permissions.

Try running the installer as an administrator when you right-click on it:
[image]